# .htaccess modify from long link to random link

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make my links from my website to look like website.com/gH25ih instead of website.com/link/index.php?id=1. So what I've tried for now is this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^link/index/([0-9]*)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_])*$ link/index.php?id=$1
```

but it's only change it from website.com/link/index.php?id=1 to website.com/link/index/1/name

Answer (score 0):

That's not how your rule is designed to work. In the rewrite you have 2 rules but only 1 variable `$1` - the random string needs to be a pointer to a db record ( in most cases ) but you have a numeric id.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)$ link/index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

should allow links like `website.com/gH25ih` but only if the `gH25ih` is somehow related to the resource you are trying to retrieve

Answer (score 0):

You will need to maintain the mapping of random URLs to the real urls but the following rewrite would work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /link/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Where the index php script would look up the random characters given.

As a side note: why obscure URLs instead of migrating from IDs to more semantic/nice ones with titles?

Comment: My content will be private for each page so I don't want users to find other content just by chaning from id=1 to id=2 and so.. btw you don't know a code to put in php file to make this working? I'm beginner so I don't really know how

Comment: Oh right. This is the last step in the puzzle so you should get the random IDs working first instead. Give it a go and if you get stuck, post a new question with the code you have tried and a good explanation of what's wrong.